# Leave voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot that plays music. I have managed to get the bot to leave the channel, but anyone in the server can disconnect it.

I have tried to add an *if* statement that requires the command author's voiceChannel connection to be equal to the bot's voiceChannel connection in that guild.

```
if(client.guildChannel.voiceChannel == message.author.voiceChannel)
        {
            message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect(); 
        }
```

this returns:

```
Property "voiceChannel" cannot be read of undefined.
```

I can't find anything on the documentation that defines which voice channel the bot is connected to in which guild.

Comment: either `guildChannel` or `author` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find on which channel your bot is, use `message.guild.me.voiceChannel`. It return the current voiceChannel of the bot. Otherwise, `client.voiceConnections.find(val => val.channel.guild.id === message.guild.id);` should also work.